# Amazon Athena sql sysdate

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, sysdate

am new to using Athena so any help greatly appreciated.

When using the below in a query, receive “column ‘sysdate’ cannot be resolved.  Worked with oracle sql but need some help what I need to use for sysdate in Athena.

Months_between (sysdate, inactivated_dt)<=12)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, trying to pull only those records where the inactivated date is equal to or less than 12 months from the current date.  Example: current date = 3/2/2021.  Record with inactivated date = 2/1/2020 would be pulled, record with inactivated date = 2/1/2019 would not.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want:

```
where inactivated_dt >= current_date - interval '12' month
```

You can review the appropriate functions and operators in the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html).